# VBA Sum returning 0

Tags: excel, vba

So I am making a macro that displays the capital gain of an investment portfolio using the variables MV and IV. It is based on the values in worksheet ws, which is based on the text entered in the combo box cmbSummary. Every time I attempt to run the macro, the message box pops up with 0, which is not the correct value. How do I solve this issue and make the message box present the correct value?

```
Dim portfolio As String
portfolio = Me.cmbSummary.Text

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets(Me.cmbSummary.Text)

Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Sheets(portfolio).Range("B" & Sheets(portfolio).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim MV As Long
MV = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Columns("L:L"))

Dim IV As Long
IV = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Columns("I:I"))

Dim CapGain As Long
CapGain = (MV - IV) / IV

MsgBox CapGain
```

Comment: What do the variables MV and IV show when you step through the code? What exactly is the content in columns L and I?

Comment: The likely reason is that the result is a value below zero (a percentage). Multiply with 100. However, I recommend that you define both MV and IV as being of *Double* data type because the result you're after must be of that type, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change variale type to Double

```
Dim CapGain As Long
```

to

```
Dim CapGain As Double
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I convert this value into a percentage with two decimals? I tried using the FormatPercent and Format functions but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @BrianWool, `100*(MV - IV) / IV `  is percent.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases where the fault lies in the testing procedure. Therefore there are different answers to your question, depending upon whether you want to fix your project or your testing procedure.

1. [Long data type] / [Long data type] returns a result of Long data type. Since the result of your division is a value below zero the MsgBox correctly displays 0 as the result. To fix the display in the MsgBox you would have to multiply with 100.
2. When you run the same calculation and assign the result to a cell (or print the result to the Debug Window) VBA will give you a result expressed in Double data type, meaning with all decimals and a floating decimal point. The display of this result in the cell will depend upon the cell's format. It could still be 0, if the cell is set to display integers only.

Therefore, the thing to do is to pay attention to the data types of the **three** variables invovled, MV, IV and the result. Secondly, MsgBox is a text handler. Don't expect it to be better at handling numbers than you profess to be yourself. If you don't pay attention, MsgBox is likely to "think" you don't care.